# Pre Requisites to start development for windows phone Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am an android developer and now I am trying to learn Mango too. What are the SDK, system requirements, IDE required to start development?

Also I am from a Java background so I know that apps for windows phone can be developed using C#. So please guide me how to set up a development environment and start development on Mango.

Comment: The question is already answered below, so I just wish to welcome you to Windows Phone development.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything you need to know is right [here at Microsoft App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/). Click on "[Download the free tools. Get started now.](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started)"

An important thing to know is that you have to be [registered with App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/membership) which takes some time (they will be checking your ID) and costs some money (99$ the last time I checked). You need this to debug on your device and to publish to the Marketplace.

For you as an Android developer the [Windows Phone Guide for Android Developers](http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/windows-phone-7-guide-for-android-application-developers) will be helpful.
The [Channel 9 jump start sessions](https://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=wriju&y=2011&m=09&d=07&WeblogPostName=windows-phone-mango-development-jump-start-available-at-channel-9&GroupKeys=) are also quite good as well as their [training course for beginners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/WP7TrainingCourse). Apart from that there is plenty of information in the web right now and the MS documentation and tutorials are really good. Keep googling, you'll find them.

Comment: thanx for replying will this development sdk work on windows xp os ?

Comment: No - the SDK will not install on XP. You need to have at least Vista SP2. If you're using your own version of Visual Studio (i.e. not relying on the version that comes with the SDK) then it will have to be at Visual Studio SP1.

Comment: There are some hacks floating around in the net, but it's not officially supported.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the xp question, I think the emulator requires at least Windows Vista, so if your employer limits you to xp, you are out of luck (in this respect also :-)